# How do I use Char(39) in a sql statement where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.  I am trying to create a recordset based off a sql statement.  In the `WHERE` clause is `'INTERNATIONAL PEOPLE' + Char(39) + 'S'`. So the single quote makes it PEOPLE'S.  This is failing.  From research it seems this should not fail.  Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Where is it failing?   Does the statement generated an error or does it not return any records?   Syntax should work, can you post the exact where clause

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can escape single quote by single quote :)

```
WHERE field = 'INTERNATIONAL PEOPLE''S'
```

Comment: "SELECT * FROM 1099 WHERE                                          Name ='INTERNATIONAL PEOPLE' + Char(39) +'S'" I also tried using the single quote instead of char(39) but it failed too.

Comment: What do you mean by failed?   Didn't return data or returned an error? What happens if you change to    Name LIKE '%INTERNATIONAL PEOPLE'+Char(39)+'S%'

Comment: I mean the database is not excepting the Sql statement.  i'll try what you suggested.

Comment: @JamieColville Do you see the error messages provided by the server? I think that says `Incorrect syntax near '1099'` which mean `1099` is not correct identifier. Put it in the brackets as `[1099]`.

Answer (score 9):

From your sample in a comment, I'm guessing it's because your table is named `1099` and the error is not really from your `WHERE` clause. T-SQL expects table names to start with an alpha character.

Try putting brackets around that:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [1099] WHERE Name ='INTERNATIONAL PEOPLE' + CHAR(39) + 'S'
```

Comment: @JamieColville Um, I'm not Hamlet. I suggested this (which solved your problem), then Hamlet added it as a comment to his answer (which did *not* solve your problem). Then you accepted his answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your query? A escaping a single quote -''- should work. Test with the code below.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#SingleQuoteTest') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #SingleQuoteTest
END

CREATE TABLE #SingleQuoteTest
(
Value   VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #SingleQuoteTest
(
Value
)
SELECT 'International People'
UNION SELECT 'International People''s'
UNION SELECT 'John O''connor'


SELECT  Value 
FROM    #SingleQuoteTest 
WHERE   Value = 'International People''s'
--WHERE Value = 'John O''connor'
```

Answer (score 0):

The apostrophe s is essential element in writing reports. Here is an example.
It gives the possessive property of a person in this case.

```
 SELECT TitleAndLastName = (Title + ' ' + LastName +CHAR(39) +'s' +  ' '  + 'address is:'), FullAddress = (AddressLine1 + City + cast(StateProvinceID as nvarchar) + PostalCode)
    FROM [Person].[Person] as p
        Inner Join [Person].[Address] as a
                   on a.AddressID = p.BusinessEntityID
            Where AddressLine1 is not null
             and Title is not null;
```

The result of the above query will have the ('s) of each person's last name.

TitleAndLastName                             FullAddress

Ms. Erickson's address is:  1226 Shoe St.Bothell 79 98011

Mr. Goldberg's address is:  1399 Firestone DriveBothell 79 98011

Good luck!